# Correct approach to multi-threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I have recently pondered on the general approach to multi-threaded code that would be most efficient. As with concurrent collections atomic mechanisms such as Compare-And-Swap are used to provide efficient implementation of collections such as queues. I was wondering whether there are any new approaches to writing multi-threaded code, for instance in java, rather than using pure `Thread` instances? Are thread pools used more often perhaps?

Comment: This smacks of premature optimization to me.  Are you sure you need to take a hit in terms of code complexity?

Comment: Not at all, I am simply wondering whether there is a shift towards certain multi-threaded programming these days in terms of how to allocate and use threads

Comment: this question is too wide-open, there are books written on this stuff

Comment: I'm not aware of any shift towards certain multi-threaded programming. But in multi-threaded programming there is a shift from lock based multi-threading to concurrency based (using atomic ops) multi-threading

Comment: @Nathan Hughes there are entire books written on every topic. The scope of the material is what really changes. The question seems fine to me, just respond in more general terms than you would if the person was asking a very specif question.

Comment: @arunmoezhi I guess that is pretty much the case. I was merely wondering in terms of entire thread perspective what new tools/approaches are used

Comment: @JohnKane Quoth the [faq]: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." The reason is that general terms invite discussion and debate over facts and a definitive answer.

Comment: @millimoose yes that was my point though. You can imagine entire books being written on CASing or locking and you can expect answers to that, though they are not as broad of a topic. What is being asked here is still specific enough to give good answers. I think what that is really referring to is questions mroe along the lines of I know nothing fix it type questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few new approaches emerging:

- message passing and actor-model, see [akka](/questions/tagged/akka) (well, the idea comes from [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang)...)
- [gpu](/questions/tagged/gpu) - massive multithreading with thousands of simple micro-threads
- transactional memory (see: [clojure](/questions/tagged/clojure))

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to blindly point you to the [Concurrent API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html), but if you work off of that you may not need to use some of the lower level concurrency controls. That really should be decided on what ever best fits your applications needs/design.

Take a look at the [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and the [ForkJoinPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) classes. Both make it much simpler to manage/maintain thread pools.